# Set default values from a parent entity

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I've created new fields in the "incident" entity and need those fields to be set by default according to some "account" fields when a an incident is created.

Of course mapping works fine but only when the incident is created from the account.

I've created a workflow, it works but it's a bit too slow...

Is there a way to do it in JavaScript?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Have you considered using a plugin? Workflows work asynchronously, but plugins work synchronously, so those default fields would be set immediately upon the creation of the `incident`. The drawback of javascript is that it would work only when using Dynamics's client and not using the API in any other way.

Comment: Hi Peter and thank you for your answer,

Could you give me a sample code so I can see how to set the incident fields according to the account entity?

Comment: Probably the best sample in the SDK is found in `SDK\SampleCode\CS\Plug-ins\accountnumberplugin.cs`, where the  account number of account is set via the plugin. It uses "late-binding" (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309731.aspx) where "early-binding" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328499.aspx) may be preferred, but that comes down to preference. If you go through all this and still aren't able to set the `incident` fields by default, probably another question would be useful at that point.

Comment: Thanks Peter ! Just after posting my comment, I actually wrote the plugin in 5 minutes. Guess I'm starting to really get how it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either javascript or a plugin to accomplish this.

**Javascript:** Edit the entity form and add your .js file under the Form Properties window.
In javascript you can use the Xrm.getAttributes("fieldname).setValue("my default"); (Google for correct syntax)

**Plug-in:** You'll hook into the "Create" message for that entity. You'll use the plugin registration tool that comes with the CRM SDK.

**Picklist:** If it's a picklist you can use the "default value" check box in the attribute properties window of the entity.